# Mongoose Select Limit 1 Data Subdocument

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have this kind of data.

```
{
    title : "Title",
    List : [
        {
            _id : '123',
            content : "Hello"
        },
        {
            _id : '234',
            content : "World"
        }
    ]
}
```

I Want to select by _id from sub document list '123' with only 1 data. I have doing It by

```
MyModel.find({'List._id' : 123}, {"List.$": 1}, function(err, doc){
    if (err){
        res.send(err);
    }
    else{
        // data here
    }
})
```

But, the result not like what I expect. They only return the List data like this?

```
{[
    List : [
        {
            _id : '123',
            content : "Hello"
        }
    ]
]}
```

How do select include the parent document so the result is just like this.

```
{
    title : "Title",
    List : [
        {
            _id : '123',
            content : "Hello"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Something like `MyModel.find({'List._id' : 123}, {"List.$": 1, title:1}, ...`

Comment: Thank's, it's work